# How to start a session for userid

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session

I want my users to enter mysite.com/earth.php and earth.php will send a sql code to my database that's update a column in the users table. So, I want the user who enters that page to change this value http://prntscr.com/4wet3o "-1" to "3" in the database for the user who enter. Not for everyone, just for the user who enters. But its not working cause the earth.php have to find the users id, and it don't find it? Do I need to start a session? I have a sessions table in my database that looks like this http://prntscr.com/4wev2k is it to any help?

The users have to login to enter Earth.php
EDIT:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

    session_start();

$_SESSION['id'] = 2; //Or a valid user ID

    $verbindung = mysql_connect("localhost","root","*****");
    mysql_select_db("lan");

if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
  mysql_query(sprintf("UPDATE users SET ally='3' WHERE id='%s'", $_SESSION['id']));  
}

     ?>
```

Comment: Please share more code that you are using for login ....

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated, use PDO

Answer (score 0):

All pages using the SESSION object should have `session_start();` at the top.  Make sure whatever page first retrieves the user id is the one that stores it in the session using `$_SESSION['id'] = $id;`.

Then on Earth.php all you need to do is `$id = $_SESSION['id'];` to retrieve it from the session.  No need to call the `session_write_close();` function.

Comment: Do you have a separate page where the user first puts in their ID or name or something?

Comment: When they login they put in their name

Comment: So that login page needs to be the one that sets the id in the session object.  Then earth.php only needs to retrieve it from $_SESSION['id']

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the logic is not correct because:

1. following lines are do nothing

   $id = $_SESSION['id'];
   $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
2. attempt to write in session after it has been closed will fail

   session_write_close();
   $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
3. following will probably return false

   if(isset($_SESSION['id']))

use instead

```
if($id) { ... }
```

--- added according to changed source ----

and replace

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET ally='3' WHERE id='$_SESSION['id']'");
```

with

```
mysql_query(sprintf("UPDATE users SET ally='3' WHERE id='%s'", $_SESSION['id']));
```

Comment: Oh, can you edit the code for me or can you explain where I should use if($id) { ... }

Comment: I edited my earth.php on my question, you can look at it

Comment: as it is should be ok. but bear in mind that after $_SESSION['id'] = 2; if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) will always be true